# Why are while loops predicated on typechecking (w/ tc_expr) the condition expression?

Tags: verifiable-c

It seems that `tc_expr` is constrained to knowledge of the typing context and nothing else so it is not possible to safely "typecheck" an expression that requires knowledge of the heap state, e.g. a pointer dereference as the condition of a while loop. Why is that and would it ever be possible for me to prove correct a loop such as:

```
char *t = ...;
...
while (*t != 0)
{
    ...
    t++;
}
```

I would think while loops could optionally be proven with a variation of `tc_expr` that does allow for pointer dereference by accounting for the heap context along with the typing context. I suspect that the thinking is that a loop condition should be a “pure” expression, but I’m ultimately curious if that is really a necessary constraint.

P.S. I realize that I could rewrite this as a for loop. My question still stands knowing that VST allows me to prove this kind of loop albeit with different syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer number 1:**  It's a design decision, one way or the other, and we found that many things are simpler (and more in the spirit of Separation Logic) if expressions do not access memory.

**Answer number 2:**  You *can* write this while loop, just as it is.  Then use clightgen with the `-normalize` flag (which you should always use anyway), and then you can verify it.  However, in such a case, the loop form will not be (strictly speaking) a Clight "while" loop, it will have it's loop-test (`if (?) then /*skip*/; else break;`) in the middle of the loop body; so you will use `forward_loop` to prove it, instead of `forward_while`.